# Handle Exception when call WCF Service to validate the form in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, validation, exception

I cant' handle with handle Exception validate form "The form cannot be blank" in [ASP.NET MVC 5](https://github.com/thanhhung90/EAP)  when I want to call WCF Services to add or search new item to this. Can you help me fix that?

WCF Services have two functions: Add new item and search item via id and be connected with Database.
Client: when I tried to add new item from WCF Service, I can't handle exception of every field in form ASP MVC ["This field can't not blank"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Kuc8q6GFjQd3FGaV94ZHZneUk/view?usp=sharing)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    localhost.Service1 ls = new localhost.Service1();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //lay list tu data de hien thi len view
        return View(ls.GetEmployees());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(String id)
    {
        List<tbEmployee> list = new List<tbEmployee>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            tbEmployee e = ls.SearchEmployees(id);
            if (e != null)
            {
                list.Add(e);
            }

        }
        return View(list);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(tbEmployee e)
    {
        e.EmployeeSalarySpecified = true;
        ls.AddEmployees(e);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", ls.GetEmployees());
    }
}
```

In a WCF Service

```
[DataContract]
public partial class tbEmployee
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(10)]

    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    [DataMember]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    [DataMember]

    public string EmployeeDepartment { get; set; }
    [DataMember]

    public double? EmployeeSalary { get; set; }
}
```

In Services1.cs

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{


    DBEmployees db = new DBEmployees();
    public void AddEmployees(tbEmployee e)
    {
        //goi tu bang
        db.tbEmployees.Add(e);


        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            Exception raise = dbEx;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    // raise a new exception nesting  
                    // the current instance as InnerException  
                    raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                }
            }
            throw raise;
        }


    }

    public tbEmployee SearchEmployees(string id)
    {
        foreach (var item in db.tbEmployees)
        {
            if ((item.EmployeeID.ToLower()).Contains(id.ToLower()))
            {
                return item;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<tbEmployee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return db.tbEmployees.ToList<tbEmployee>();

    }
}
```

Comment: So, what problem are you having?

Comment: It never ceases to amaze how many people post "I have a problem with *xyz*", but never **STATE THE ACTUAL PROBLEM**.  If you broke your leg, would you go to the doctor and say "I don't feel well" and then have them run multiple tests to diagnose the condition?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I can't handle Exception to validate form "The Field cannot be blank" in ASP.NET MVC 5 when I try to call WCF Servies to add  new item. github.com/thanhhung90/EAP –

Comment: What do you mean that you can't handle the exception?

Comment: When my input string is null, i want to show results like as in this image but i don't know to handle this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Kuc8q6GFjQd3FGaV94ZHZneUk/view

Comment: This is my project on github:https://github.com/thanhhung90/EAP

Comment: The image you posted in using the jquery client side validation, you need to check your fields before you send them to the WCF service, this is if i understood your problem..

Answer (score 0):

If we want to throw exception from WCF host application and want to catch it in client application, 
then we should use FaultException.

It has mainly tow types 1) Weak type and 2) Storngly type

Confirm first your service behavior to includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true":

```
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="ProductsBehavior">
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Type 1) Refer below code for Weak Type:
WCF Host appliction code example:

```
List<string> productsList = new List<string>(); 
try
{
    while (productsReader.Read())
    {
        string productNumber = productsReader.GetString(0);
        productsList.Add(productNumber);
    }
}catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new FaultException("Exception reading product numbers: " + e.Message, new FaultCode("Read/GetString"));
}
```

WCF Client application code:

```
try
{
  //access service code in this try block
}
catch (FaultException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e.Code.Name, e.Reason); //catch fault exception here
}
```

Type 2) Refer below code for strongly type fault exception:
WCF Host application code example:

```
// Classes for passing fault information back to client applications
[DataContract]
public class DatabaseFault
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DbOperation;
    [DataMember]
    public string DbReason;
    [DataMember]
    public string DbMessage;
}
```

//modify the IProductService as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProductsService
{
    // Get the product number of every product
    [FaultContract(typeof(ConfigFault))]
    [FaultContract(typeof(DatabaseFault))]
    [OperationContract]
    List<string> ListProducts();
    …
}
```

//modify the ProductsServices class and throw fault exception like below:

```
List<string> productsList = new List<string>(); 
try
{
    while (productsReader.Read())
    {
        string productNumber = productsReader.GetString(0);
        productsList.Add(productNumber);
    }
}catch (Exception e)
{
    DatabaseFault df = new DatabaseFault();
    df.DbOperation = "ExecuteReader";
    df.DbReason = "Exception querying the AdventureWorks database.";
    df.DbMessage = e.Message;
    throw new FaultException<DatabaseFault>(df);
}
```

And catch exceptions at WCF Client application code as follows:

```
try
{
    //access service code in this try block
}
catch (FaultException<DatabaseFault> df)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DatabaseFault {0}: {1}\n{2}", df.Detail.DbOperation, df.Detail.DbMessage, df.Detail.DbReason);
}
catch (FaultException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e.Code.Name, e.Reason);
}
```

Refer this link for more detail: [Fault Contract](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376303/Fault-Contract-Handling-Errors-in-WCF-and-A-Very-S)
Please let me know, is this works for you ?

Comment: Thank for your help. But i only want to handle exception  when i tried to input nothing to form in ASP.NET MVC web like this image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Kuc8q6GFjQd3FGaV94ZHZneUk/view

Comment: @user2212512 Do you want to validate your model in MVC project? for that you refer this link: [MVC Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710702/ASP-NET-MVC-Server-Side-Validation)